# ASP.NET Web Form Update Command Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sql-update

I have a web form that I am using to alter a particular record in a database. The fields are populated by data via the C# code behind using SqlDataReader as follows:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=My_DB;Initial Catalog=BillingAuths;Integrated Security=True";
        string queryString = 
            "SELECT * FROM [AuthRecords] WHERE [ID] = @RecordID;";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString,connection);
            connection.Open();
            int qRecord = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RecordID"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordID", qRecord);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
               {
                EmailCntyDate.Text = (reader["EMailCountyDate"].ToString());
                EmailCtyCnct.Text = (reader["EMailCountyContact"].ToString());
                EmailCntyAppDate.Text = (reader["EMailCountyAppDate"].ToString());
               }
```

This works fine: The fields are populated with the correct values from the DB. From here, the intent is for the user to edit the information, then activate an UPDATE command by clicking a button. The code for this is in HTML.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DB_Auths" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" UpdateCommand="
    UPDATE [dbo].[Records]
    SET [EMailCountyContact]=@uEMailCountyContact,
        [EMailCountyDate]=@uEMailCountyDate,
        [EMailCountyApp]=@uEMailCountyApp
    WHERE [ID] = @RecordID">
  <UpdateParameters>
     <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecordID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="null" QueryStringField="RecordID" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EmailCntyDate" Name="uEMailCountyDate" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EmailCtyCnct" Name="uEMailCountyContact" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EmailCntyApp" Name="uEMailCountyApp" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Sumbit" Text="Save" OnClick="Sumbit_Click" />
```

This is the code-behind activation (in theory) for the UPDATE process:

```
    protected void Sumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DB_Auths.Update();
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Response.Write("WARNING: WRITE TO DATA WAREHOUSE FAILED! Error:" + error);
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, no error message is returned and I redirect as of the update were successful; however, when I check the database, the record is exactly the same as it was before.

What gives?

Comment: can you please keep a break point and check what value is passing in the RecordID i guess it may be cleared on the post back. i'm not sure but please double check it

Comment: That did it! Thanks for lending a noob a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your page_load code block w/ this statement:

```
if (!IsPostBack) { }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

This prevents code from being executed and overwriting the textbox inputs when the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

can you please keep a break point and check what value is passing in the RecordID i guess it may be cleared on the post back. i'm not sure but please double check it